# How do I setup a Symfony 3 entity that may occasionally need to break foreign key constraints?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

For the purposes of my question lets assume that I have 'Users' table and a 'Referrals' table. The Referrals table has a user_id field which needs to be constrained to the Users.id so I can do something like:

```
$referral->getUser()->getId();
```

Here is where the issue has arisen before in the past. In some special cases like in the case of a Referral (a person who refers a customer to buy a product) there can be cases where no one referred a customer (user_id=0).

Trying to set up Symfony entities where a user_id in the referral table is 0 will cause doctrine to throw a fit and it wont allow the foreign key to be setup. Even if I bypass the fk constraints in MySQL in order to restore a backup later or whatever, it will always cause issues and besides, its not good database design.

However I have had this circumstance come up several times and was wondering if there is a way I could setup my Referral entity to basically say "Hey, give me User if there is one but otherwise return NULL?"   I know this would mean not defining relationships in the entities but then how could/would you return a User?

Comment: I would say that if your business logic sometimes breaks the constraint, then perhaps the constraint should not be there at all.  Maybe you could store such edge case users in another table?

Comment: Why don't you create a fake user that will be assigned when user = 0 like before?